# Allow all https domains in frame-ancestors

Tags: security, spring-security, content-security-policy

I would like to add CSP for frame-ancestors so that security scans won't complain about flammable content.
I would like to add CSP something like below.

````
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
        .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("frame-ancestors https://*.*;")
        ;
    }```
Once the application is loaded I got the below message in console. 
```The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors contains an invalid source: 'https://*.*.' It will be ignored.```
````

Comment: `https://*.*` has incorrect syntax. Use `https:` or `https://*` instead.

Comment: Also it doesn't make much sense, nor does it mitigate the usual frame related threats, so scans will still likely find it as an issue, at least the correct ones.